# Passport.js Local Mongoose's setPassword not working

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I am new Passport.js. I was using passport-local-mongoose making forget password API. for that I was using setPassword method as define by https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose.

Now this whole code is working fine. No error rises and mail is sended after the setPassword Execution. But password doesn't resets. It work only with the old password.

```
router.patch("/forget-password", async (req, res, next) => {
  var user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "There is no such user registered." });
  } else {
    console.log(user);
    if (String(req.body.otp) != String(genOTP)) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "OTP does not match. Please check again." });
    } else {
      user.setPassword(req.body.password, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          res.statusCode = 500;
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          readHTMLFile(__dirname + "/mail/reseted.html", function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
              res.statusCode = 500;
              res.send(err);
            } else {
              try {
                sendEmail(
                  user.username,
                  "Security alert",
                  html
                );
                return res
                  .status(400)
                  .json({ msg: "Password Reset Successfully." });
              } catch (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server Error" });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Please suggest a solution to the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation setPassword method doesn't save the document.

> Using `setPassword()` will only update the document's password fields,
> but will not save the document. To commit the changed document,
> remember to use Mongoose's `document.save()` after using `setPassword()`.

```
else {
    try {
        user.save() // here
        sendEmail(
            user.username,
            "Security alert",
            html
        );
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ msg: "Password Reset Successfully." });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server Error" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the solution. But I have tried it and it is not working.